# ff Domain Layer test with disable, enable trigger context

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, domain-layer

I'm trying to use `fflib_SObjectDomain.getTriggerEvent(Accounts.class).disableAfterUpdate();` on my **Account Domain Class** to stop **after updates** operations to be fired from **after insert** operations for the account object.

The reason is that some of the methods are executing the same logic on `afterInsert` and `afterUpdate` for that domain class. I just want to avoid re-executing the same logic when it is not necessary. For this reason I'm using `fflib_SObjectDomain.getTriggerEvent(Accounts.class).disableAfterUpdate();` as you can see below:

```
/**
 * After Insert context operations
 *
 **/
public override void onAfterInsert() {
    List<Account> newList = (List<Account>) Records;
    Map<Id, Account> oldMap = (Map<Id, Account>) ExistingRecords;

    List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
    for (Account account : (List<Account>) Records) {
        accountIds.add(account.Id);
    }

    fflib_SObjectDomain.getTriggerEvent(Accounts.class).disableAfterUpdate();
    AccountService.sumChildAccountFleetFields(newList, oldMap);
    AccountService.signUpForWeeklyDigestAndCampaignFor(newList);
}

/**
 * After Update context operations
 *
 **/
public override void onAfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> existingRecords) {
    List<Account> newList = (List<Account>) Records;
    Map<Id, Account> oldMap = (Map<Id, Account>) existingRecords;

    AccountService.sumChildAccountFleetFields(newList, oldMap);
    AccountService.signUpForWeeklyDigestAndCampaignFor(newList);
    AccountService.listUnsubscribe(newList);
    validatePersonEmail(Records);
    uow.commitWork();
```

Now, the issue is that when I try to execute a test method to update a number of accounts, the `onAfterUpdate` method never gets called.

I did some tests on the UI to fired a simple email validation method which it is part of the `onAfterUpdate` method:

```
private static void validatePersonEmail(List<SObject> accountsList) {
        for (Account account : (List<Account>) accountsList) {
            if (String.isBlank(account.PersonEmail)) {
                account.addError('You must provide an Email for this account');
            }
        }
    }
```

That works, so on a real scenario the after update is working.... but how can I test this?
I tried several things but the tests never run over the Account Domain class `onAfterUpdate` method. So any tips on this would be great...

Comment: There's no method to re-enable it?

Comment: Yes, there is the enableAfterUpdate, but then it fires when I do insert operations :( which it is what I don't want..

Comment: You need to bookend the insert operation. Disable > Insert > Enable > Update.

Comment: Right, did that on the Test class and now it runs over the onAfterUpdate but it is throwing  an error : INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id] .... thanks.. if you post an answer I will select it as the correct one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bypass trigger logic, you need to bookend your disablement. Typical flow is as below:

```
@IsTest static void myTest()
{
    // disable trigger
    // insert data
    // enable trigger

    Test.startTest();
        // update data
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert against behavior
}
```